# A confusion about Fragment in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is the second day I learn android studio.
I do not know why there is an error here.
help me please！！

```
//MainActivity.java
    public void ChangeFragment(View view) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentView, fragment2);   
//error is there: "Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.myfirstapp.Fragment2', required: 'android.app.Fragment'"

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

@

```
//Fragment2.java
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment2, container, false);

        Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                text.setText("I am a Fragment");
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

@

```
//activity_fragment2.xml
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">
    </LinearLayout>
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (which you should), then you need to use [`getSupportFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()), not `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: if i using getFragmentManager()，what i need using？android.support.v4.app.Fragment is Android studio automatic generated(Alt +Enter)

Comment: There are many, many bug fixes in the support fragments that will not be present in the framework fragments. Why can't you use `getSupportFragmentManager()`?

Comment: ok， thank you， i just follow the official steps to study. Now I'm looking for a tutorial on getSupportFragmentManager(). You understand, everything is difficult at the beginning.But now i do not understand anything,so I can go and see the other.After all, all roads lead to Rome....But I really want to know,what i need using ? if i use the getFragmentManger()?

Comment: Thanks again,as you said, I have succeeded in calling and using the fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
FragmentManager fragmentManager = **getFragmentManager()**;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

import android.app.Fragment;
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {..}
```

@

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
FragmentManager fragmentManager = **getSupportFragmentManager()**;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {..}
```